# How to set the body of a PUT request in Elixir/phoenix with Plug.Adapters.Test.Con

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So I have test setup as follows using Elixir/Phoenix and ESpec testing framework:

```
let :response do
  resp = build_conn() |> put("/kites/#{id_function()}", [horizontal: "more", default: true])
  Poison.Parser.parse!(resp.resp_body, keys: :atoms!)
end
```

When I call response(), I get an error such as:

```
** (Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {Plug.Adapters.Test.Conn, %{chunks: nil, method: "PUT", owner: #PID<0.46.0>, params: nil, ref: #Reference<0.0.5.1528>, req_body: ""}}
      (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:354: Poison.Encoder.Any.encode/2
      (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:213: anonymous fn/4 in Poison.Encoder.Map.encode/3
      (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:214: Poison.Encoder.Map."-encode/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
      (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:214: Poison.Encoder.Map.encode/3
      (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:213: anonymous fn/4 in Poison.Encoder.Map.encode/3
      (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:214: Poison.Encoder.Map."-encode/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
      (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:214: Poison.Encoder.Map.encode/3
      (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:213: anonymous fn/4 in Poison.Encoder.Map.encode/3


1 examples, 1 failures

Finished in 1.0 seconds (0.76s on load, 0.24s on specs)
```

What is going on?  Am I passing the parameters to PUT request correctly?

Comment: Is that the whole error message? Strange that there is no line in the stacktrace from your test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks for me like you want to encode map while you got a tuple.

You have:

```
{Plug.Adapters.Test.Conn, %{chunks: nil, method: "PUT", owner: #PID<0.46.0>, params: nil, ref: #Reference<0.0.5.1528>, req_body: ""}}
```

a tuple with `{some_val, %{}` where `%{}` is a map. You probably want to encode just a map, so it's second element. You can take second element from tuple by using: `elem(resp.resp_body, 1)`

Maybe it will work:

```
Poison.Parser.parse!(elem(resp.resp_body, 1), keys: :atoms!)
```

Or just create a map from it with:

```
Enum.into(resp.resp_body, %{})
```

I'm not sure if I'm pointing in right place, but it seems like `resp.resp_body` has more inside than you expect.

---

**One more thing, remember that keys: `:atoms!` reuses existing atoms, i.e. if `:some_var` was not allocated before the call, you will encounter an argument error message.**

So maybe just deleting it may help:

```
Poison.Parser.parse!(resp.resp_body)
```

Comment: The error in the question is `Poison.EncodeError`. I don't think that error can be emitted by `Poison.Parser.parse!`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the root cause ended up being there was an Ecto.Schema.Struct in the response I was trying to parse.